# Method to solve as system of PDE in this form

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

Suppose I have two differential equations of the form,

$$ \frac{\partial K}{\partial r} = f(r,\theta) $$

$$ \frac{\partial K}{\partial \theta} = h(r,\theta)$$

I want to be able to determine $K$ such that both differential equations are true. **Is there a method for doing this?**

Comment: Note: This only has solutions if $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta}=\frac{\partial h}{\partial r}$$ due to symmetry of partial derivatives.

Comment: Could you please explain why this should be true? Thank you.

Comment: We know that $$\frac{\partial^2 K}{\partial \theta\partial r}=\frac{\partial^2 K}{\partial r \partial \theta}$$ Then you can compute each of these by differentiating your first equation wrt $\theta$ and the second wrt $r$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the first, by integration

$$K(r,\theta)=\int f(r,\theta)\,dr=F(r,\theta)+c(\theta)$$ and from the second

$$K(r,\theta)=\int h(r,\theta)d\theta=H(r,\theta)+d(r)$$ where $c,d$ are uknown functions.

By identification, $F,G,c,d$ must be such that

$$K(r,\theta)=F(r,\theta)+c(\theta)=H(r,\theta)+d(r).$$